# Running a VBA Script in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

If I have a good VBA script for alphabetizing a mailing list in a meeting invitation, how would I apply it in Outlook 2013?
Is there a place to paste this, and maybe after pasting it there, it'll run automatically?

Also, would I have to paste this into every invitation I build, or will this be the default condition of my mailing lists?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a place to paste this?**

> When in Outlook, press Alt+F11.  That's where you can develop your
>   macros/functions. You will probably have to modify your code before
>   you run it though. An alternative to the hotkey is enabling the Developer tab and clicking 'Visual Basic'. You can read about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx).

**It'll run automatically?**

> It depends on your implementation. I can think of three on the top of my head:
>
> 1. [You can create a rule to run a script on specific actions.](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)
> 2. [You can run it on a schedule](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/running-outlook-macros-schedule/)
> 3. [You can run it when Outlook starts up.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/28cb4d2e-1580-4081-88cc-79f2220a6b45/running-vba-code-automatically-every-time-outlook-starts-up?forum=outlookdev)
>
> [Since you are using Outlook 2013 you may need to modify the registry to allow scripts to be run from a rule.](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)

**Would I have to paste this into every invitation I build**

> Nope. When a macro is created, it stays created even when you close out of Outlook (unless you don't save it!!).

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like good advice. I'll see if I can get this to work. We have very limited permissions here, so things aren't always straight-forward!